# Why does Azure fail with HTTP ping when deploying a react app?

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

Got a react app, created with 'create-react-app', running on Mac OSX. (with no problems).
Once I deploy to Azure, it seems to be wrapping it in a docker container, and this is where the problem starts...

It deploys ok, but when the app starts, I get the following errors

```
2020-05-31T08:35:19.112Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 7733:8081 --name stock-market-game_0_73cadc78_middleware -e WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=10.10 -e APPSETTING_WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=10.10 -e WEBSITE_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=* -e WEBSITE_CORS_SUPPORT_CREDENTIALS=False -e WEBSITES_PORT=443 -e Port=443 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=stock-market-game -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=stock-market-game.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=8e5bf20839a2c0a3c50f56fdb0fe9eef2cfdaa38cc8dc7b192b8300d0263d579 -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 appsvc/middleware:2001061754 /Host.ListenUrl=http://0.0.0.0:8081 /Host.DestinationHostUrl=http://172.16.0.3:443 /Host.UseFileLogging=true
2020-05-31T08:35:22.388Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container stock-market-game_0_73cadc78 for site stock-market-game
2020-05-31T08:35:38.450Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container stock-market-game_0_73cadc78. Elapsed time = 16.0613799 sec
2020-05-31T08:35:53.604Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container stock-market-game_0_73cadc78. Elapsed time = 31.2159855 sec
2020-05-31T08:36:04.158Z ERROR - Container stock-market-game_0_73cadc78 for site stock-market-game has exited, failing site start
2020-05-31T08:36:04.158Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container stock-market-game_0_73cadc78_middleware for site stock-market-game
2020-05-31T08:36:08.026Z INFO  - Container stock-market-game_0_73cadc78_middleware for site stock-market-game initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
2020-05-31T08:36:08.037Z ERROR - Container stock-market-game_0_73cadc78 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 443, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2020-05-31T08:36:08.127Z INFO  - Stopping site stock-market-game because it failed during startup.
```

I have added the app settings for PORT and WEBSITES_PORT (as in the log above).  But i cannot see why it is failing?

Any ideas?

Comment: Ping fails because the container does not start. You need to figure out why your container is not starting.  Enable application logging, download the logs or stream them to find what's wrong.